# How to perform validation of a array field using formik and yup validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup, primereact

I am working in React JS . I need to implement validation using Formik and Yup for an array field as show below. Validation condition is such a way that the input time should not be equal to or between the existing time(The time that had already entered . Eg: if I enter 14.05 it should show an error, because the input time is already between 14.00 (start) and 03.00 (end) ). How can I validate the fields I think concept is clear. If there any doubts please do ask.
[image]

```
// API values
//home_delivery_monday_times: Array(3)
//0: {start: "09:00", end: "11:00"}
//1: {start: "14:00", end: "03:00 "}
//2: {start: "11:30", end: "13:00 "}
//length: 3
 <Formik
                            initialValues={formData}
                            enableReinitialize={true}
                            validationSchema={yup.object({
                                settings: yup.object({
                                    home_delivery_monday_times:
                                        yup.array().of(yup.object({ start: yup.string() })).test("is-valid", "The value shouldn't equal or between the existing", function (value) {
                                            return (
                                                // Validating conditions
                                            )
                                        })

                                })
                            })}
                            onSubmit={(values: any, { setSubmitting }) => {
                                console.log("values", values)
                            }}
                        >
                            {formik =>
.....}
```

```
 

     {formik?.values?.settings?.home_delivery_monday_times?.map((item: any, index: any) => (
                                                                                <>
                                                                                    {index != 0 &&
                                                                                        <div className="p-col-12 p-sm-2 p-md-2" />
                                                                                    }
    
                                                                                    <div className="p-col-5 p-sm-4 p-md-4">
                                                                                        <label>Start</label>
                                                                                        <Field as={Calendar} value={item?.start ? new Date(`01-01-2000 ${item?.start}:00`) : ''} onSelect={(e: any) => { formik?.setFieldValue(`settings.home_delivery_monday_times.${index}.start`, moment(e?.value).format("HH:mm")) }} name={`settings.home_delivery_monday_times.${index}.start`} readOnlyInput={true} timeOnly />
                                                                                        <div className='p-col-12'>
                                                                                            <ErrorMessage name={`settings.home_delivery_monday_times.${index}.start`} component={FormErrorMsg} />
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                    </div>
    
                                                                                    <div className="p-col-5 p-sm-4 p-md-4">
                                                                                        <label>End</label> <br />
                                                                                        <Field as={Calendar} value={item?.end ? new Date(`01-01-2000 ${item?.end?.trim()}:00`) : ''} onSelect={(e: any) => { formik?.setFieldValue(`settings.home_delivery_monday_times.${index}.end`, moment(e?.value).format("HH:mm")) }} name={`settings.home_delivery_monday_times.${index}.end`} readOnlyInput={true} timeOnly />
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    <div className="p-col-1 p-sm-2 p-md-2">
                                                                                        {index != 0 &&
                                                                                            <FiXCircle name="name" color="red" size="20px" onClick={() => formik?.values?.settings?.home_delivery_monday_times?.splice(index, 1)} />
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </>
    
                                                                            ))}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**
I advice making use of the [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs) library then you can use the code below:

```
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { Formik, Form, Field, FieldArray, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import moment from "moment";

export default function App() {
  const isValid = (timeSlots) => {
    if (!timeSlots) return;

    // compare each slot to every other slot
    for (let i = 0; i < timeSlots.length; i++) {
      const slot1 = timeSlots[i];

      if (!slot1.start || !slot1.end) continue;

      const start1 = moment(slot1.start, "HH:mm");
      const end1 = moment(slot1.end, "HH:mm");

      for (let j = 0; j < timeSlots.length; j++) {
        // prevent comparision of slot with itself
        if (i === j) continue;

        const slot2 = timeSlots[j];

        if (!slot2.start || !slot2.end) continue;
        const start2 = moment(slot2.start, "HH:mm");
        const end2 = moment(slot2.end, "HH:mm");

        if (
          start2.isBetween(start1, end1, undefined, "[]") ||
          end2.isBetween(start1, end1, undefined, "[]")
        ) {
          return `Overlapping time in slot ${j + 1}`;
        }
      }
    }
    // All time slots are are valid
    return "";
  };

  const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log(values.mondayTimes);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container m-3">
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ mondayTimes: [{ start: "", end: "" }] }}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
          mondayTimes: Yup.array()
            .of(
              Yup.object().shape({
                start: Yup.string().test("startTest", "Invalid Time", function (
                  value
                ) {
                  if (!value) return true;
                  return moment(value, "HH:mm").isValid();
                }),
                end: Yup.string().test("endTest", "Invalid Time", function (
                  value
                ) {
                  if (!value) return true;
                  if (!moment(value, "HH:mm").isValid()) {
                    return this.createError({ message: "Invalid Time" });
                  }

                  if (
                    moment(this.parent.start, "HH:mm").isSameOrAfter(
                      moment(this.parent.end, "HH:mm")
                    )
                  ) {
                    return this.createError({
                      message: "End time must be after start time"
                    });
                  }

                  return true;
                })
              })
            )
            .test("timesTest", "Error", function (value) {
              const message = isValid(value);
              return !message;
            })
        })}
        render={({ values, errors }) => (
          <Form>
            <FieldArray
              name="mondayTimes"
              render={(arrayHelpers) => (
                <div className="">
                  {values.mondayTimes.map((time, index) => (
                    <div className="row" key={index}>
                      <div className="col-5">
                        <div className="mb-3">
                          <label htmlFor="" className="form-label">
                            Start
                          </label>
                          <Field
                            className="form-control"
                            name={`mondayTimes.${index}.start`}
                          />
                          <ErrorMessage
                            className="form-text text-danger"
                            name={`mondayTimes.${index}.start`}
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="col-5">
                        <div className="mb-3">
                          <label htmlFor="" className="form-label">
                            End
                          </label>
                          <Field
                            className="form-control"
                            name={`mondayTimes.${index}.end`}
                          />
                          <ErrorMessage
                            className="form-text text-danger"
                            name={`mondayTimes.${index}.end`}
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-2 mt-4">
                        <button
                          className="btn btn-sm btn-danger m-2"
                          type="button"
                          onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}
                        >
                          -
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ))}

                  {isValid(values.mondayTimes)}

                  <button
                    className="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2"
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() =>
                      arrayHelpers.insert(values.mondayTimes.length, {
                        start: "",
                        end: ""
                      })
                    }
                  >
                    +
                  </button>
                  <div>
                    <button className="btn btn btn-primary m-2" type="submit">
                      Submit
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
            />
          </Form>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/time-slots-validation-kr5ch?file=/src/App.js) for you to try out

Comment: Could you be more specific about the issue ?

Comment: By entering start time its not check all previous time that are scheduled on monday. My expecting result is that when user enter start time(Monday) its will check all scheduled previous value (condition is like time is equal to start or end time, Between start and end time, greater than end time ). The entered time is satisfy any one of the above condition,then it will throw an error to that feild ,Error mesage like time is already exist or any other

Comment: hello any idea about my issue

Answer (score 1):

Although this post is quite old, it helped me out tremendously as a starting point for my own availability editing component.

To answer the question, finding if two intervals overlap is quite easy.

```
const t1 = [1,3]
const t2 = [2,5]
```

If we have two intervals like the above where each number represents an hour we can use the formula below to determine if they overlap:

```
const isOverlapping = Math.max(1,2) <= Math.min(3,5)
```

**In plain terms,** this equation says: An interval overlaps if the end time of the first interval happens **after** the start time of the next interval.

[image: overlapping image]

credit @[baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/finding-all-overlapping-intervals)

Now, to implement this in code we need to compare all intervals with each other use the above formula for comparison.

[image: https://www.baeldung.com/wp-content/ql-cache/quicklatex.com-1b986cd4f29bf73a735f7c306c7fa42b_l3.svg]

credit @[baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/finding-all-overlapping-intervals)

Since @Rishabh Singh provided the answer of the Naive approach. I will provide a revised version that makes some of the below improvements:

1. Replaces moment.js with the smaller, more modern date-fns library
2. Replaces the Naive comparison O(n^2) with the faster Sweep-Line Approach O(n*log(n))
3. Adds support for multiple days of week
4. Adds formik validation for when start/end times are not in a valid hh:mm format
5. Adds formik validation for when time slots are not in ascending order

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/time-slots-validation-enhanced-nhsldq?file=/src/App.js) link